# jQuery: show only one item per click

Tags: jquery, css

I have small issue maybe you can help me with?
I have HTML div's and show and hide functionality.

I want only to show one (1) div per click, not all.
i made a jquery code but it shows all divs.

need suggestion.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfcglen/pLfbwve5/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var toggleContent = jQuery('.insideContent');
    toggleContent.addClass('hidden');
    var thisElemnt = $(this);
    jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {
        thisElemnt.find('.insideContent').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
    });


});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var toggleContent = jQuery('.insideContent');
  toggleContent.addClass('hidden');
  var thisElemnt = $(this);
  jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {
    thisElemnt.find('.insideContent').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
  });


});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.list {
  direction: inherit;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="col-lg-2 workImage">
    <div class="itemTitle">
      <h2 class="page-header  text-center">Item</h2>
      <button class="button">Open Project</button>
    </div>
    <div class="insideContent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 workImage">
    <div class="itemTitle">
      <h2 class="page-header  text-center">Item</h2>
      <button class="button">Open Project</button>
    </div>
    <div class="insideContent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 workImage">
    <div class="itemTitle">
      <h2 class="page-header  text-center">Item</h2>
      <button class="button">Open Project</button>
    </div>
    <div class="insideContent">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thisElemnt is defined BEFORE the click binding, so it doesn't relate to the clicked button. @guradio's answer demonstrates that.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var toggleContent = jQuery('.insideContent');
    toggleContent.addClass('hidden');
    var thisElemnt = $(this);
    jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.itemTitle').next('.insideContent').toggleClass('hidden show');//use $(this) to apply only to click elemt
    });


});
```

Use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest parent `.itemtitle` then
use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the target div then 
use [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to show and hide the target div

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pLfbwve5/6/)

Comment: @user3785944 glad to help mate can you tick the check mark to give the OP answered already

Comment: Also, i changed the code a little bit, i used "removeClass" and "addClass" instead.

Comment: @user3785944 it is the same but if you are more confident with that then please do so